# mvc glyphicon bootstrap mobile not working

Tags: css, codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons, mobile-browser

I have followed a lot of questions and answers about why glyphicons from bootstrap don´t work in mobile browsers or in determined browser, but it is still not working in my case.
Here are some specifications of the environment:

1. Localhost whith Ubuntu 14.04
2. MVC web page (code-igniter)
3. Apache 2
4. Bootstrap 3.1.1
5. Windows phone 7.9 & 8
6. Android phone emulated (this one is the only one in which browser the icons are displayed)
7. Not smartphone Mobile web browser

Bootstrap works fine in each mobile and desktop pc in the LAN but glyphicons are displayed only in desktop pc and emulated android.

font face URL edited with and without dots.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-  opentype'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons-halflingsregular') format('svg');
}

 //or

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    src: url('/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
    src: url('/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-  opentype'), url('/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'), url('/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), url('/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons-halflingsregular') format('svg');
}
```

mime types in `.htaccess` and `mime.conf`

```
 application/vnd.ms-fontobject .eot
 application/x-font-ttf        .ttf
 application/x-font-woff       .woff
```

I also tried different tags

```
<em></em>
<i></i>
<span></span>
```

Nothing worked for mobile browser.
All other bootstrap stuff works fine in mobile and desktop